# Modelling in separate pieces VS one object

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, workflow

Starting situation: Creating (nearly) Photorealistic renders.

Question: How do I correctly model for photorealistic renders (for applying shaders)?

My Approach: Using a Primitive and model it by extruding/insetting etc.
Another idea of mine: separate all entities like they are in reality.

Does applying Materials to a single Object via Selection photorealistic?
Or is separating my mesh into several different meshes (eg. sword: blade:metal; hand guard:ceramic; Hilt:Wood) the more professional way to go about it?

Comment: And how would i go about adding Paint ?

Comment: to reach "photorealistic" results you have several ways, depending on the model and the scene context, at least: you could apply real photos as textures, of course, but for some objects you need to set a shader (cycles renderer is your best choice for this, apart external renderers), but you also have lighting that counts on realistic results, and reflections of the surroundings (hdri will help), atmosphere absorption... you can learn several tecniques and get better and better using them, in the end you will know how to do it... it's just a long path. But you can't do real "reality" in a pc!

Comment: adding to that above, a mesh in Blender can have multiple materials, any mesh part can use a separate material, you just add another material to the object, and then apply it to selected vertices... this will give you material diversity keeping vertices count down... you can then add textures, painting, displacements, a whole lot of things to reach the best results... but CG is - always - about tricking an observer to believe what he see can be real... so tricks also are valid everywhere.

Comment: suggested reading: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40065/is-blender-right-for-me-a-photographer-creating-3d-renderings/40068#40068 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im and https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/photorealism-explained/

Comment: Very much related: [What are the benefits of modeling in one piece, or as separate parts?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14482/2217)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about it is to keep it all as one mesh, that the way most pros do it and it prevents your scene from getting to cluttered
If you like to be able to have all your objects separate Keep them all together in one object and then separate them inside edit mode. However Do not have one object for your scene. a good scene can have anywhere from 3(for a object display) or 1000(for a simulation)

Also if you want to learn a bit about photo realism, go check out Andrew Prices blenderguru.com them website is really heavy but they have a lot of good tips as to how you can make something realistic