# How would industry-professionals approach this?

Tags: objects, workflow, snapping

[image: This is a small scene I was working on, and I though it would make a good example]
I am trying to figure out how professionals in the animation industry would approach this sort of building. If you take a look at the green details of the windows, those are a separate object from the main building, as well as the little lip underneath the windows.

Would this be how they would do it professionally? Or, would they probably make these pieces all out the main building? And if they would use separate objects like I did, is it okay if they overlap, because I've heard mixed opinions on that. I'm just trying to learn the best habits now, so that one day, if I do get a job in the industry, I know what to do.

I hope this makes sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: "*industry professionals*" What industry? Games, cinema, animation, engineering, 3D Printing? What is the final purpose of said model? Even in the same industry I am sure different "professionals" would approach this different ways. As it stands this question is very opinion based and not a good suit for this site. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65022/modelling-in-separate-pieces-vs-one-object

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, I edited the post, but I am referring to the animation industry. I understand that different people approach things in different ways, but you would think that there are certain practices that are widely accepted as the norm among industry professionals. I was under the impression that this was a forum for Blender users to help each other out, but you're saying this isn't the right site, did you have another in mind? In addition, if that question is indeed too opinion-based, there are still other questions in the post if you keep reading.

Comment: Please do not ask many questions on the same post. Different questions should be asked separately in individual posts.

Comment: @cegaton okay, I changed it!

Comment: This is not a "forum" per-se, and is best suited for concise questions, if in doubt see the [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). For opinion based questions it is probably best to ask at [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org/)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Oh okay, thank you! I probably never would have found that website!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends.**

If the final result was to be animated, then they would most likely make any moving part a different object. But on non-moving parts, such as the Door Overhang, it would probably be left to the individual artist's discretion what to do on that individual piece. For your purposes, I would do whatever you are most comfortable with, and whatever you think will be most efficient for that individual scene.